# Install MySql and load Dump in a Docker image

Tags: mysql, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile I install MySql-Server

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# INSTALL MYSQL
RUN apt -y update
RUN apt -y install mysql-server
RUN service mysql start
```

but what root password is it now? Is there a easier way to maybe install MySql-Server and intially load a mysql-dump-file?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the [MySQL offical](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) docker image, which has proper entrypoint and manages complex task like setting an initial password and DB dumb on boot or during build time if you extend from base image.

You just need to use below docker-compose and map your DB file to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d.`

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Currently, this is only supported for `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ROOT_HOST, MYSQL_DATABASE, MYSQL_USER, and MYSQL_PASSWORD.`

**Initializing a fresh instance**

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions `.sh, .sql and .sql.gz` that are found in
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL
>   dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
>   data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
>   by the `MYSQL_DATABASE` variable.